# Typeorm relations - Use 1 object with all the relations, or query each relation separately

Tags: typescript, orm, typeorm

Suppose I have these entities:

```
@Entity()    
export class Kid {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;
        
    @Column()
    name: string;
      
    @OneToMany(() => Pet, pet => pet.kid)
    pets: Pet[];
}
    
@Entity()
export class Pet {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;
        
    @Column()
    name: string;
        
    @ManyToOne(() => Kid, kid => kid.pets)
    kid: Kid;
}
```

And suppose I have a function:

```
SerializeKid(Kid kid) {}
```

Which will be called like:

```
const kid = await kidsRepo.find({where: {publicId: 1, relations: pets}})
const result = SerializeKid(kid)
```

I got a suggestion to define that function like:

```
SerializeKid(kid: Kid, pets: Pet[]) {}
```

Which will be called like

```
const kid = await kidsRep.find({where: {publicId: 1})
const pets = await petsRepo.find({where: {kid: kid.Id}})
const result = SerializeKid(kid, pets)
```

The reasons were:

1. Assuming someone else uses that function, he may not query for the relation 'pets' beforehand, thus sending a Kid object with no pets, and that may cause confusion. To that my answer is that the function should sanity check the pets property isn't undefined.
2. More explicit indication that the caller to this function needs to query for the relations explicitly, saving DB query time in case the relations aren't needed. to that my answer is that the sanity check will take care of that, in the 1st solution you also don't have to query for the relations.
3. Separation of concerns (sort of like #2 isn't it?)
4. DB - 1 big query (with the relations) will take long and can't be split into several lighter queries in case we have many DB instances and want the queries load to be split across some instances

What do you think is the best solution in this case?
I lean towards the 1 query with the relations, 1 object that contains all, and sanity check at the called function, simply because querying each relation one by one and sending all the relations one by one as parameters to the function seems very ugly to me